# Mysql query with sub-selects taking too long..

Tags: mysql, sql

Every 5 minutes my historical table is updated (by another process) with a new record (TAG_NAME remains the same but TIME and VALUE are updated). I am using the following query to return the LATEST record while also grouping by TAG_NAME.

```
SELECT 
TAG_NAME,max(TIME) as max_time, 
(select value from historical where TAG_NAME=hist.TAG_NAME order by time desc limit 1) as max_value 
FROM historical hist 
WHERE TIME IS NOT NULL AND GROUP BY TAG_NAME;
```

This query is taking as long as 1 minute on a table with 100k rows. Can anyone help me optimize this query?

Much Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to prepend EXPLAIN to that query and review the result?

Comment: For reference: See [Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html)

Comment: you put a group by in your where clause!! TF! How did it work?

Comment: MySQL is very tolerand :-)

Comment: you mean not simply `select TAG_NAME, max(time) as max_time from historical group by TAG_NAME`? What differs from this solution?

Comment: that was essentially my first query - (but you forgot my VALUE column). The problem was that I was getting a unique TAG_NAME and the max(TIME) but the VALUE was correlating to the max(time) record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the combined maximum, so if two times are the same you get the biggest value.

```
select TAG_NAME, max(concat(time,value)) as time_value
from historical 
group by TAG_NAME
```

If necessary you can split time and value in mySQL, but you can also split it in the app.

Comment: This was perfect.. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
TAG_NAME, max(`TIME`) as max_time, max(`value`) as max_value
FROM historical
WHERE `TIME` IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY TAG_NAME
;
```

Comment: He wants value where time is max not just max(value)

Comment: I can't consider this query because max(value) isn't desirable.. The latest entry -- found with max(time) may have a much lower value than some previous entry. Originally my query was `select TAG_NAME, max(time) as max_time from historical group by TAG_NAME;` but that was bringing back TIMES and VALUES that weren't from the same record!

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d210/1

```
SELECT 
h.*
FROM historical h
LEFT JOIN historical h1
ON h.TAG_NAME = h1.TAG_NAME
  AND h.time<h1.time
WHERE h1.time IS NULL
```